# Deployment of a Django project

Tags: django, deployment

Its my first project and I have it ready on my computer! I have read many tutorials about passenger and other ways but have a more basic question which I could not find the answer...

When deploying should I just copy my directory structure and files and then run syncdb to create the database? Or should I do all the steps of creating the project, than the app and then copying my files? Or something else?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying, you can just copy your files. Everything should work fine, as long as on the node you are deploying to has django installed.

Wheter or not to run syncdb (or the new migrations) depends on wheter or not you have changed your models. Of course, after first deployment syncdb has to be invoked (if you aren't using the sqlite database framework and you're not uploading your database along with your files, of course).